# How can I make this Invoke-Webrequest ask for all the pages?

Tags: powershell, pagination, invoke-webrequest

The command below loops through a file which contains activity ID numbers, and sends a request that checks what members attended this activity. It's a PowerShell command from within a batch file.

```
Powershell "Get-Content .\idsonly.txt | ForEach-Object {Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Headers @{ \"api-version\" = \"2\" ; \"Authorization\" = \"Bearer %token%\"} -Uri %uri%/$_/Members?pagesize=100`&fields=memberid`,hasattended | Select-Object -Expand Content}" ">> memberssact.txt"
```

The problem is that some activities have more than 100 members attending, and this will only give met the first 100 members for each activity. How do I make it ask for additional pages, if there is one? The maximum number of results that may be returned is 100 and [this is a server-side limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72351413/how-can-i-make-this-invoke-webrequest-ask-for-all-the-pages/72351586?noredirect=1#comment127818126_72351413).

Possibilities (but I don't know how to implement them):

1. I have a list of the activity IDs next to the number of attendees, from which I can work out how many pages the list of attendees will be.
2. There is a "next page url" in the response header if there are more pages (but how do I tell PowerShell to GET it, if it's there?)
3. Least favourite, but could just brute-force increasing the number of the page requested and tell it to stop when no response received, but not sure how.

I have provided a sample response header below:

```
{
  "access-control-expose-headers": "Request-Context",
  "cache-control": "no-cache",
  "content-length": "2",
  "content-security-policy": "default-src 'self' ;base-uri 'self';  object-src 'none'; connect-src 'self'; worker-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self'; child-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; manifest-src 'self'; prefetch-src 'self'; ; font-src 'self' fonts.gstatic.com data:; img-src 'self' data: *.ac.uk *.swagger.io; media-src 'self' ; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'report-sample'; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline' 'report-sample' https://fonts.googleapis.com; report-uri /log",
  "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  "date": "Mon, 23 May 2022 15:37:06 GMT",
  "expires": "0",
  "last-modified": "Mon, 23 May 2022 15:37:07 GMT",
  "pragma": "no-cache",
  "request-context": "appId=cid-v1:3abf1c0e-2963-49e7-bc48-18ed8b04daa3",
  "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000",
  "x-content-type-options": "nosniff",
  "x-frame-options": "DENY",
  "x-pagination": "{\"currentPage\":3,\"pageSize\":100,\"totalCount\":178,\"totalPages\":2,\"previousPageLink\":\"https://url.uk/activities/597850/students?page=2&pageSize=100&sort=hasattended&fields=studentID%2Chasattended\",\"nextPageLink\":\"\"}",
  "x-xss-protection": "1; mode=block"
}
```

Comment: What API are you working with? Pagination isn't going to work the same across all APIs

Comment: First and simplest thing to try would be if the API complains if you use `pagesize=1000` (or whatever a realistic size is for your dataset, add zeros as necessary).

Comment: Yeah now I see that there is a `pageSize` variable

Comment: If I ask for 200, it will just give me the first 100. The API isn't accessible to the public, but if helpful I'll add the response header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've provided a sample response header, I've updated the code sample below as well as provided an explanation for how it works:

> **Note:** This example is not invoking PowerShell as a one-liner. You should move this piece to a script with a parameter for each `%VARIABLE%` you use in your original command. `$Token` and `$Uri` are the variables I've changed to a PowerShell format. I have also removed otherwise-unnecessary string escapes. This could be modified to be a one-liner of course, but for any real scripting logic it should be part of its own script, function, etc.

```
Param(
  [string]$Token,
  [string]$Uri,
  [string]$IdsFile
)

$ids = Get-Content $idsFile

foreach( $id in $ids ) {

  $nextUri = "$Uri/$id/Members?pagesize=100&fields=memberid,hasattended"

  while( $nextUri ) {
    $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Method Get -Headers @{
      "api-version" = "2"
      Authorization = "Bearer $Token"
    } -Uri $nextUri

    $response.Content >> membersacct.txt
  
    $paginationHeader = $response.Headers.'x-pagination' | ConvertFrom-Json
    $nextUri = $paginationHeader.nextPageLink
  }
}
```

---

Essentially, what this does is:

- Added input parameters to facilitate the CMD variables you were using as well as allowing you to provide the file path to the `idsonly.txt` file. This can be used with a PowerShell script or within a PowerShell function definition.
- Set `$nextUri` to the initial URL you want to get results from
- Perform the web request, assign to the `$response` variable
- Writen (append) `$response.Content` to file
- Convert the `x-pagination` header value to a PowerShell object using `ConvertFrom-JSON`.

  - This results in a larger object than you may need but it handles the parsing of the JSON so you don't have to.
- Set `$nextUri` to the next page, even if there is no next page
- If there is no `$nextPage`, the `while` loop will exit

  - This relies on the truthiness of `$nextUri`; in other words, an empty string will evaluate to `$False` while any other string value will evaluate to `$True`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this when I can and get back to you

Comment: @NeMo I've updated the sample to reflect the sample response header you edited into your question. So this may work for you as written now.

Comment: I made one additional fix FYI in case you copied an old revision of this answer

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I didn't mention that org policy prohibits running ps1 scripts, but allows me to run ps commands from within a batch file. Doesn't make much sense to me, but asking them to change it would probably be fruitless. I made your command work by replacing the newlines with semicolons and putting the escapes back in. Figuring out how to make the escapes work with batch and powershell is fun (:

Comment: @nemo In 2022, that is unfortunate . I would personally try making the case to allow *signed* scripts, and make sure your scripts are signed with an org-trusted key.